# Google event tracking used by a Delphi desktop application

Tags: delphi, google-analytics, delphi-xe

I've come to a crazy idea to use Google event tracking in Delphi desktop application. I want to track users behaviour workflow to make application better. But it's in javascript.

Is it possible somehow to do it directly from application? Or do I need for example to make a webpage which communicates with Google event tracking API and application sends REST queries to that webpage?

Or maybe I can do it without javascript at all and directly from application?

Comment: I hope you consider your obligations to your end-users before you spend too much time on this. It seems like the kind of thing that you would need to clearly explain up-front, otherwise you'll be accused of all sorts of 'evil'.  And if you do properly explain it, and offer an opt-out, I can't imagine that your opt-in would be higher than 10%. I think you would be much better off with focus-group testing, even by looking over the shoulders of friends and relatives as they use your app.

Comment: @Chris So webpages can use Google Analytics and desktop applications can not - can you explain me difference in them? I run webpage on my computer and Analytics collects data, so why can't desktop application do it? By the way I found http://deskmetrics.com/ for desktop applications, but I want to know, how can I do it in Analytics for free...

Comment: The difference is that a website is server-side, while a desktop is client-side.  Google Analytics gives you aggregate data about what groups of people are doing on **your** site; your idea would collect individual data about what specific people are doing on **their** personal copy of your program.  There's a huge difference there.

Comment: @Mason Application only collects event data, what user is opening, what is cancelled etc. I think this is not a crime :)

Comment: It may be a crime in some places, based on local privacy laws.  Seriously.  Even if it isn't, 'what a user opens' just by itself may be sensitive information.  Respect their privacy, and ask before you gather the information and let them see what information you've gathered before you send it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be very careful with this, and warn your users.

Though software running locally is a different thing than software running from a web-site in a browser, the interconnectedness of software is increasing. So is the general feeling in the public on what is right and not to communicate.

For instance, a lot of software 'phones home' to check for the latest version without even asking permission to their users. I can understand that some users have a problem with that, but it indicates the general opinion on this is shifting. The vendors can track usage statistics based on that 'phone home' alone.

I'm not sure if the Google Event Tracking would be the best way to solve usage tracking from a desktop application, but the general idea (collecting usage statistics and error information) can work out very well.

Software from big vendors have been getting usage statistics from their software for years, and they ask their users up-front if sending statistics is OK, and at the time of an error, each time ask them if that is OK too.

In fact the book "[Why Software Sucks ... and What Can You Do About It](http://www.whysoftwaresucks.com/)" and presentations from [David Platt](http://www.rollthunder.com/) explains really well how to do this and how to communicate this to your users.

You need to do this in a very anonymous way, and you can because basically you are interested in these things:

- what is the largest percentage of errors
- what is the largest percentage of features used
- what is the smallest percentage of features not used

As long as you communicate percentages, it is clear to explain to your users that the data will be very non-specific.

On the other hand: being able to focus on the actual errors can improve your software a lot.

The errors communicated back to you can contain much detail, so you need to either strip that detail out, or be very upfront with your users indicating which details are being sent to you when communicating individual errors.

--jeroen

Comment: Ok, found a way to do it...no answers found, but your answer was most educational...

Comment: I don't think this is the answer to the question. It is the expression of your concern.  Therefore it can be a comment, but has no business being written as an answer.

Comment: This would never fit in a 600 character comment, plus I tried to answer the underlying sentiment in the series of questions. So it is not as simple as "answer to the question". In that light it has very much business being an answer in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I developed my own solution (I called it 'softmeter') to do exactly this. It is a dll that will do all the REST queries to Google Analytics.
There is sample Delphi code that wraps the DLL in a Delphi class so sending an event is simple as

```
dllSoftMeter.sendEvent('Conversion events', 'Donate clicked', 1);
```

If you do not mind using 3rd party libraries, you can use it.
In fact I found that most software using it, is Delphi made software.

Here is a more extended sample of the Delphi code for the implementation.
https://www.starmessagesoftware.com/blog/track-delphi-pascal-gui-application-google-analytics

You will need of course to get consent from the end-user.